# One-boot system 'flag' solution on linux?

Tags: node.js, linux

I'm developing a project on the Raspberry PI 3 running Raspbian. I want to use ESCs to control my brushless motors. The problem is ESCs need to be calibrated once after supplied power.

What I'm looking for is a way to store a 'flag' that I can set and read from my program *and* that is resetted every system boot (so that the program doesn't repeat the calibration procedure after it, not the system, is restarted). Is there any way to do so (I'm using nodejs, so it would be nice if I could do so from javascript)?

Comment: You should probably show some of the relevant code. Depending on when the motors are brought online (I'm guessing late because of Node.JS), create the flag in `/var` using a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally decided to use the /var/run directory to store the flag